# Helper functions in Kiwi specs

Tags: ios, objective-c, kiwi

I have a few repetitive specs that I would like to DRY up.  The common functionality doesn't lend itself to moving into a `beforeEach` block.  Essentially, it's object creation and is 4 lines for each of 12 objects, I'd like to turn those 4 lines into a single function call.

Where can I put helper functions in a Kiwi spec?

In RSpec I can just put `def` between spec blocks, but that doesn't appear to be possible here.  I've even tried skipping the `SPEC_END` macro and adding that content myself so I could add functions inside the @implementation from `SPEC_BEGIN` but that doesn't seem to work, either.

**Correction**... I can manage something that kind of works with hand-coding the `SPEC_END` macro.  I had the end } mis-placed.  But still, it fails, because the method isn't in the `@interface`.

Comment: see this https://github.com/kiwi-bdd/Kiwi/issues/138

Answer (score 34):

Create your helper function as a block just after the SPEC_BEGIN:

```
SPEC_BEGIN(MySpec) 

NSDate* (^dateFromString) (NSString *) = ^NSDate* (NSString *dateString) {
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM-dd-yyyy"];
    return [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
};


describe(@"something", ^{
    NSDate *checkDate = dateFromString(@"12-01-2005");

...
});

SPEC_END
```

Comment: Is it possible to have an async helper? Let's say if I wanted to authenticate against a remote server in the helper.

Answer (score 8):

You could also create a straight C function above the `SPEC_BEGIN()` scope.

```
NSString *makeAString () {
    return @"A String";
}
```

Or if you have helper functions that will be used across several Spec files, place these functions in a separate file and import the header.  I've found this to be a great way to clean up my Specs.

Comment: I could swear I tried that, but I don't know for sure anymore. I will have to go back and check it out. This is more or less what I wanted.

Comment: This gives me the following warning:

warning: no previous prototype for function '<function name>' [-Wmissing-prototypes]

This can be solved by making the method static:

static NSString *makeAString() { ... }

Comment: @SebastienMartin I've never seen this error.  Are you declaring the function before you're using it?

Answer (score 5):

[supermarin](https://github.com/kiwi-bdd/Kiwi/issues/138#issuecomment-14724430) suggests the following method:

```
@implementation KWSpec(Additions)

+ (void)myHelperMethod:(Car*)car {
            [[car shouldNot] beNil];
        };

@end

SPEC_BEGIN(FooBarSpec)

describe(@"A newly manufactured car", ^{
    it(@"should not be nil", ^{
        [self myHelperMethod:[CarFactory makeNewCar]];
    });
});

SPEC_END
```

Another option is as [Doug suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11801048/67824):

```
SPEC_BEGIN(FooBarSpec)

void (^myHelperMethod)(Car*) = ^(Car* car){
        [[car shouldNot] beNil];
    };

describe(@"A newly manufactured car", ^{
    it(@"should not be nil", ^{
        myHelperMethod([CarFactory makeNewCar]);
    });
});

SPEC_END
```

The nice thing about it is that it lends itself nicely to async scenarios:

```
SPEC_BEGIN(FooBarSpec)

__block BOOL updated = NO;

void (^myHelperAsync)() = ^()
{
    [[expectFutureValue(theValue(updated)) shouldEventually] beYes];
};

describe(@"The updater", ^{
    it(@"should eventually update", ^{
         [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:"updated" 
                                                 object:nil 
                                                 queue:nil 
                                            usingBlock:^(NSNotification *notification)
         {
             updated = YES;
         }];
         [Updater startUpdating];
         myHelperAsync();
    });
});

SPEC_END
```

Finally, if your helper method resides in another class, [gantaa](https://github.com/kiwi-bdd/Kiwi/issues/138#issuecomment-26154947) suggests a clever hack:

```
@interface MyHelperClass

+(void)externalHelperMethod:(id)testCase forCar:(Car*)car
{
    void (^externalHelperMethodBlock)() = ^(){
        id self = testCase; //needed for Kiwi expectations to work
        [[car shouldNot] beNil];
    };
    externalHelperMethodBlock();
}

@end

SPEC_BEGIN(FooBarSpec)

describe(@"A newly manufactured car", ^{
    it(@"should not be nil", ^{
        [MyHelperClass externalHelperMethod:self forCar:[CarFactory makeNewCar]];
    });
});

SPEC_END
```